# How do I select from MySQL through PHP via Swift?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

I have a TableViewCell in my Main Storyboard named as "cell" and a label named as "company"

I want to select and display a row from MySQL where the company name is the same as my `cell.company.text`.

It is possible?

I query from mySQL with this PHP code (this is list all company names from companies table):

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT company_name FROM companies");

$outp = '{"companies": [';
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $outp .= '{"company":"'. $rs["company_name"]     . '"},'; 
}
$outp .="]}";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
```

And with this Swift code I get the company names to my app TableCell:

```
cell.Company.text = "Company Name: " + companies[indexPath.row].company
```

I want to do a select query from MySQL where `company_name = cell.Company.text`

How can I do it?

Comment: Please give your question a meaningful title. You might also want to read [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to load data from your server by starting a get or post request. Well I assume you already have a php file to read data from `DataBase` as well as a swift project. If You have the above mentioned things then follow the following steps.

**Step 1:** Add the following Pod to your `ios` project.

[Almofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Read about cocoapods [here](https://cocoapods.org/) if you don't know what is it.

**Step 2** Now add the following code in your ViewController

```swift
let data = ""
                let url = URL(string: Helpers.url_get_categories)!
                var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                request.httpBody = data.data(using: .utf8)
                Alamofire.request(request).response{
                    response in
                    let responseString = String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8)
                    self.LoadDataFromJson(data: responseString!)
                }

 func LoadDataFromJson(data: String){
        if let dataFromString = data2.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
            let json = try! JSON(data: dataFromString)
            //Read Data here

        }else{
            print("Error while parasing json")
        }
    }
```